# Move files with todays modified date to other folder then delete files older then two weeks

Tags: vba, powershell

Script needs to be run every one week (via task scheduler) and achieve the following:
When the script runs, all files on the date of script run (modified date for files) in certain folder needs to be copied to other folder, when copied, delete everything older 2 weeks from the original folder.

See screenshot for more explanation

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zSD0cgn.png]

I have something with powershell:

```
$path = "C:\FromFTP\*.*"
$Destination = "C:\Backup"
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path))
{
    If($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-1).date)
    {
        Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $Destination
    }
}
```

But maybe it could be also with vba..

Can someone help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: Lots of us can help with that, but we need something to help from.  Can you show what code you have written/tried so that we can help you fix it?  Please remember we're not here to write the code for you, but to help you fix problems you're having with whatever you came up with :)

Comment: I have something like this with powershell:
$path = "C:\FromFTP*.*"
$Destination = "C:\Backup"
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path))
{
 If($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-1).date)
 {
  Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $Destination
 }
}

Comment: You'll need to click the edit button just under your question and paste it in, code isn't really readable in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$Path = "C:\FromFTP";
$Destination = "C:\Backup";

$Today = (Get-Date).Date;

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | 
    Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -ge $Today) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $Today.AddDays(1)) } | 
    Move-Item -Destination $Destination;

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | 
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Today.AddDays(-14) } | 
    Remove-Item;
```

The first line gets every file that was last written to (`LastWriteTime`) sometime between midnight today an before midnight tomorrow.  Obviously it's difficult to write files tomorrow, but it makes it easy to run the script for a date in the past, too.

The second line deleted every file that was first created (`CreationTime`) before 14 days before today.  The number of days might be off by one, depending on how you count.

Comment: This is not working. But I don't get any errors after running the script.

Comment: I've changed the script from CreationTime to LastWriteTime and that part in the script (deleting older than 14 days) is working.
The part where it have to move the files is not working

Comment: @kiki1989sb Does the first part return anything with just the Get-ChildItem and Where-Object portions?  If so, try adding the `-Verbose` option to the Move-Item command (i.e., `Move-Item -Destination $Destination -Verbose;`) to see what the script is trying to do.  I'd double check the permissions on the destination folder for the account the script is running under, too.